# Update table data in switch in mui-datatables while my data is in boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I want to update my boolean data while displaying in Switch in each row (data fetched from firestore )**

The data is being displayed correctly but while clicking on it to change it either true of false it's not working.
Here is my code..

```
{
      name: "is_verified",
      label: "Verified",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
         
                        <Switch
                          checked={value}
                          onChange={
                            async (e) => {
                              e.preventDefault();
                             //tableMeta.rowData[0] is my document id
                             const docsRef = doc(db, "vendors" , tableMeta.rowData[0])
                             await updateDoc(docsRef, {
                                value: e.target.checked,
                                 
                              })

                            }
                          }
                          name="active"
                          color="primary"
                        />
          )
      }
      }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? The code to update a document looks fine. Are there any errors?

Comment: no error in console. it is not updating on firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved

```
{
      name: "is_verified",
      label: "Verified",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return ( 
              <Switch
              checked={value}
              onChange={
                async (e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  updateValue(e.target.checked);
                 //tableMeta.rowData[0] is my document id
                 const docsRef = doc(db, "vendors" , tableMeta.rowData[0])
                 await updateDoc(docsRef, {
                  is_verified: !value,
                     
                  })

                }
              }
              name="active"
              color="primary"
            /> 
          )
      }
      }
     }
```

[Online Doc](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/component/index.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).